# IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 Browse Repositories

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

I can't find the "Browse Repositories" option under Plugins in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition 2018.3.2 and I am pretty sure that I had it before.
I need to install the Flutter plugin from repositories. [image: Here is the plugins screen]

```
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3.2)
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have it already installed - check the *Installed* tab. If it's there you probably missing the Dart plugin, which should be installed together with Flutter plugin. Try to reinstall Flutter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes in the newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA.

"Marketplace" is similar to the "Browse Repositories" option.

If you have already installed a plugin it will be in your "installed" tab.

Also, check if have somehow disabled the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Flutter plugin is not compatible with 2018.3 versions. I downgraded to 2018.2, now it is fine.